# Math Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Describe all $2\times3$ matrices $A1$ and $A2$, with row echelon forms $R1$ and $R2$, such that $R1 + R2$ is the row echelon form of $A1 + A2$. Is it true that $R1= A1$ and $R2 = A2$ in this case ? Does $R1 - R2$ equal $rref(A1 - A2)$ ? (rref => reduced row echelon form)

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could have
$$ A_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr},\ A_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr},\ A_1 + A_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$
$$ R_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr},\ R_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr},\ R_1 + R_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 2\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$
where $R_1 \ne A_1$.